# SharePoint list to track Server CU, SPs, Hotfixes, Date Applied, etc

Tags: list

I am being lazy today. LOL. Does anyone have a splist to track sharepoint related server updates (cu, sps, hf, etc.).

I would like to create a report or dashboard where list will be populated with the all the available updates (sp, cu, hotfix) so I can better prepare for the next updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why create the list when it already exists?

- 2007 [Updates Resource Center for SharePoint Products and Technologies](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sharepointserver/bb735839)
- 2010 [Updates for SharePoint 2010 Products](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/ff800847.aspx)

Looks like it lists all the latest software updates include Cumulative Updates and Service Packs.

Comment: Just applied June CU as my rtm came with SP1. Now, If I want to deploy December CU, do I need to deploy all the CU that's between June and December? December CU has all the fixes that in those CUs?

Comment: You will only need the December *Cumulative Update*. The cumulative part means it includes all the previous fixes.